# Laravel 5.5 Giving a an error message saying method has no action

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have a named route in web.php:

```
Route::get('editFact/{id}'.'FactsController@edit')->name('editFact');
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
public function edit($id) 
{  
     $fc = Item::find($id); 
     $ct = Category::orderBy('title')->get(); 
     return view('admin.facts.edit',['fc' => $fc, 'ct' => $ct]); 
 }
```

I have defined both the models in the use area.

```
use App\Item; 
use App\Category;
```

The view is definitely there but when I try to access it I am getting:

***Route for [admin/editFact/{id}FactsController@edit] has no action.***

I have an index function in this controller that works fine:

```
public function index() 
{ 
    return view('admin.facts.index'); 
}
```

Any ideas please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in Route::get. Edit code

```
Route::get('editFact/{id}'.'FactsController@edit')->name('editFact');
```

to

```
Route::get('editFact/{id}','FactsController@edit')->name('editFact');
```

Comment: What a pillock I am. Just could not see it!